# How can I convert protein distance maps and sequences to a pdb files?

Tags: proteins, pdb, machine-learning, deep-learning

How can I convert protein distance maps and sequences to pdb files?

For the same problem, in the case of a model predicting the structure of a protein, such as AlphaFold, how do we convert the generated output tensor to a PDB file and visualize it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what your outputs look like now. PDB files are supposedly provided as part of alphafold predictions (see github page: https://github.com/deepmind/alphafold#alphafold-output). PDB format described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_Data_Bank_(file_format)